# is there a way to use Anko commons in the fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

[image]

I am trying to call `toast{..}` function using `Anko library`. It is simple calling the `toast{...}` function in activity, but I can't find a way to call the function inside fragment.

so, is there a way to use Anko commons in the fragment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go through the documentation of Anko `toast{..}`, its implementation is:

```
/**
 * Display the simple Toast message with the [Toast.LENGTH_SHORT] duration.
 *
 * @param message the message text resource.
 */

inline fun Context.toast(message: Int): Toast = Toast
        .makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        .apply {
            show()
        }
```

The `toast{..}` is an extension function for the `Context` class. Hence, it can be called from only that class which inherits from `Context` class.

**So, to use `toast{...}` in your fragment you will have to use `activity?.toast("YOUR_TOAST_MESSAGE_HERE")`.**

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

implement this

```
 implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko:0.10.6"
```

import in your fragment

```
import org.jetbrains.anko.support.v4.toast
```

in your code

```
toast("string")
```

**its working for Me**